# When WithLatestFrom operator is not enough

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I just stumbled upon a situation where I'm not being able to avoid keeping state, but I still get the feeling that this could be achieved using only Rx:

I've got two observables, the main one invokes the onNext every time a user inserts a value:

```
-- RV -- RV -- RV -- IV ------ ... ->
```

The other one invokes onNext every the user wants to remove the last value

```
------------------------- X -- ... ->
```

Now the thing is, I'm only concerned when the user removes a Relevant value, so in this case I wanted the following sequence:

```
-- RV -- RV -- RV ------------ ... ->
```

At this point I'm able to get what I want simply by using the WithLatestFrom operator, however in the following case:

```
-- RV1 -- RV2 -- RV3 -- IV --------- RV4 ----- ... ->

--------------------------- X -- X ------ X -- ... ->
```

I don't know how I can create a observable who returns me the following stream:

```
------------------------------- RV3 ---- RV4 -- ... ->
```

Caption:
    **RV** = Relevant value

### **IV** = Irrelevant value

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

var values =
    scheduler
        .CreateColdObservable<int>(
            new Recorded<Notification<int>>(2, Notification.CreateOnNext(0)),
            new Recorded<Notification<int>>(4, Notification.CreateOnNext(1)),
            new Recorded<Notification<int>>(6, Notification.CreateOnNext(2)),
            new Recorded<Notification<int>>(10, Notification.CreateOnNext(3)),
            new Recorded<Notification<int>>(12, Notification.CreateOnNext(4)));

var removes =
    scheduler
        .CreateColdObservable<Unit>(
            new Recorded<Notification<Unit>>(7, Notification.CreateOnNext(Unit.Default),
            new Recorded<Notification<Unit>>(8, Notification.CreateOnNext(Unit.Default)));

values
    .Select(x => x.ToString())
    .Merge(removes.Select(x => "X"))
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

scheduler.Start();
```

Comment: Can you please provide source observables with sample data and what the outputs should look like? I'm after C# code that I can use to construct an answer.

Comment: I was hoping for sample code that runs and produces the sample values and for you to tell me what the output of the samples should be. Have you used `TestScheduler`?

Comment: Oh, ok, I will create a sample using TestScheduler.

Comment: I have one for you. Hang on.

Comment: Can you let me know what the output of that sample should be?

Comment: The output would be 2 if "2" is a relevant value, otherwise the output would be nothing. I just updated the question's original expected stream

Comment: Can you please let me know what the output of the sample I posted in your question?

Comment: I guess the output of the sample would be: 0 -- 1-- 2 -- X -- 3 -- 4

And I would like a stream with only the removed value: -- 2 --

Comment: You're not being very clear. I do not understand how you are turning your input into output. None of your examples show the `X` coming out. If we take my example as `-0-1-2X3-4-------------(etc)`, with the dashes being pauses, what is the expected output you want?

Comment: If 2 is a "relevant" value: ----2------ otherwise ----------------

Comment: I don't want "ifs". I've given you two specific sets of input and I want to know what the specific output of your operator would be.

Comment: I just updated your sample: Imagine I want only want X if the previous value is an odd number, then the output should be: -----1------- at tick 8. Because the remove on tick 7 targets the value 2 and the remove on tick 8 targets the value 1 
Basically I want the (N) previous values according to a predicate. I'm sorry if I'm not sounding very clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194364/discussion-between-enigmativity-and-eduardo-brites).